# Was bedeutet "Abb."?

Tags: abbreviation

In einem deutschen Eiscafé in München steht auf der Speisekarte hinter einigen Speisen:

> (ohne Abb.)

*Abb.* ist wahrscheinlich eine Abkürzung. Was bedeutet sie? Ich habe den Kellner gefragt, aber er wusste es nicht.

Comment: *"Ohne Abbreviatur"* wäre überaus ironisch. ;)

Comment: Echt traurig, dass der Kellner das nicht wusste.

Comment: jedoch ABB: Asea Brown Boveri oder auch Allman Brother Band (Blues, mit Tendenzen ins Countryhafte, aber auch etw. souly. Excellente Gittarenbeherrschung).

Comment: `hinter einigen Speisen` :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Abbildung*

Das Eis war auf der Karte nicht mit Foto abgebildet.

Answer (score 8):

Abbildung.

It's a bit technical, used like the english *fig.*, as in "Abb. 1 - Eine Kugel Eis".